# How do I return all of the child objects - I can't get SelectMany to work

Tags: linq

I have a class

```
    public class Foo
    {
       public IList<Foo> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooList
    {
       public IList<Foo> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to be able to get all of the Foo objects in one list, instead of a hierarchy.

I have tried

```
    IEnumerable<Foo> result = Items.SelectMany(f =>  f.Items);
```

but this just gets me the items in that specific object - it doesn't get all the items in all of the child objects.

I also tried

```
    IEnumerable<Foo> result = Items.SelectMany(t => t)
```

But I get the error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: A FooList has a list of foos.  Each Foo also has a list of foos, and each of these foos has a list of foos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly easy to knock together a "flatten-this-tree" LINQ-like function that you can use in the more general case:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
{
    HashSet<T> added = new HashSet<T>();
    Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    foreach(T t in source)
        if (added.Add(t))
            queue.Enqueue(t);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        T current = queue.Dequeue();
        yield return current;
        if (current != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> children = childSelector(current);
            if (children != null)
                foreach(T t in childSelector(current))
                    if (added.Add(t))
                        queue.Enqueue(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you have a `FooList`, you can use

```
var allFoos = myFooList.Items.Flatten(foo => foo.Items);
```

to get all the `Foo`s in the list, along with all their children and all *their* children and...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `FooList` instance called `fooList`:

You'll need to define a method like this in the `FooList` class:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetRecursiveFoos()
{
    return Items.Concat(Items.SelectMany(x => x.Items));
}
```

and then call

```
IEnumerable<Foo> result = fooList.GetRecursiveFoos();
```

Comment: This doesn't actually recurse. It'll just get the top levl and one further level.

Comment: @Rawling Right. I made a mistake when reading your code and got the wrong impression about the data structure.